# how to create pivots to avoid ID duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I Have the following table(´information´)

```
ID    |    value
1     |    A
1     |    B
2     |    A
3     |    A
3     |    B
3     |    C
4     |    A
```

How can I use a query to render the following table?

```
ID   |   A   |   B   |   C   | 
1        X       x      null   
2        X      null    null
3        X       X       X
4        X      null    null
```

I have the following code:

```
select id,  CASE WHEN value= 'A' THEN 'X'
   ELSE NULL END AS A,
CASE WHEN value= 'B' THEN 'X'
   ELSE NULL END AS B,
CASE WHEN value= 'C' THEN 'X'
   ELSE NULL END AS C
FROM information group by id;
```

but I ot one row per Id as well.

Comment: you can't, without making a really ugly 3-way joined table. `case` can only look at the current record's values, which is just one single value. to get the values of the OTHER similar records, you'd need subqueries/joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN value= 'A' THEN 'X' END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN value= 'B' THEN 'X' END) AS B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN value= 'C' THEN 'X' END) AS C
FROM information 
GROUP BY id;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2342c/1)

Answer (score 0):

You just need aggregation functions:

```
select id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'A' THEN 'X' END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'B' THEN 'X' END) AS B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'C' THEN 'X' END) AS C
FROM information
group by id;
```